# Embedded A-Frame and rayOrigin: mouse

Tags: three.js, aframe

This is what I'm working on: [360 Tour](http://demo.tangram3ds.com/hobsons-landing/junkroom.html). I have an embedded A-Frame scene, and just need a simple hotspot icon that will load a new page when clicked with a mouse (taking viewer to a different room on the tour). It has to be embedded so I can keep a css-styled, responsive HUD docked to the side of the frame.

It seems like the active clickable area is being offset depending on the window size. [This thread sounds similar to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442056/a-frame-mouse-tracking-changes-when-scene-is-embedded) but their solution was an updated component script, and that script is now incorporated into the main A-Frame script(?).

Is there a cursor setting I'm overlooking? I'm new to A-Frame as of...(*checks watch*)...last week and new to Javascript since a week before that, so I won't be surprised if it's something simple I'm misunderstanding.

Any guidance or tips greatly appreciated. Here's my A-Frame:

```
<div id="vrwindow">
  <a-scene embedded="true"  antialias="true" cursor="rayOrigin:mouse" >
      <a-assets>
        <img id="granite" crossorigin="" src="images/granite.png">
        <img id="quartzite" crossorigin="" src="images/quartzite.png">
        <img id="frost" crossorigin="" src="images/frost.png">
        <img id="fieldstone" crossorigin="" src="images/fieldstone.png">
        <img id="riverrock" crossorigin="" src="images/riverrock.png">
        <img id="baltic" crossorigin="" src="images/baltic.png">
        <img id="alpine" crossorigin="" src="images/alpine2.png">
        <img id="linen" crossorigin="" src="images/linen.png">
        <img id="hawthorne" crossorigin="" src="images/hawthorne.png">
        <img id="hemingway" crossorigin="" src="images/hemingway.png">
        <img id="hickory" crossorigin="" src="images/hickory2.png">
        <img id="hotspot" crossorigin="" src="images/bedroom.png">
      </a-assets>

      <a-sky id="bigimage" src="images/guestroom.jpg" rotation="0 -90 0"> 
        </a-sky>    
      <a-circle navigate-on-click="url: junkroom.html" 
       src="images/bedroom.png" position="-2 0 -8"></a-circle>
      <a-camera fov="70"  look-controls>    </a-camera>
  </a-scene>          
</div>
```

and the component script I'm using

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('navigate-on-click', {
schema: {
  url: {default: ''}
},

init: function () {
  var data = this.data;
  var el = this.el;

  el.addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.top.location.href = data.url;
  });
}
});
```

Comment: Can you use an I-Frame? And if the HUD needs to communicate to the A-Frame app, you can use I-Frame postmessage.

Comment: Yes! This worked beautifully. Very new to javascript so I'm still learning what solutions are even available, thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aframe embeded scene with cursor mouse ray-origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065510/aframe-embeded-scene-with-cursor-mouse-ray-origin)

Answer (score 1):

High-level answer was to move the A-Frame app into an I-Frame and use postMessage to control the A-Frame scene so it can navigate while keeping app state and a 2D HUD.